# sql - join without duplicating the key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join two tables with several hundred columns, like this:

```
select * from a, b where a.key = b.key
```

The problem is that I get a table that has

```
Key | Key | Row1 | etc...
```

Without naming all of the columns explicitly ("`select a.key, row1, ... from a, b where a.key = b.key`"), is there a way I can limit the query so that it only returns one of the keys?

Comment: no you cannot, you need to specify columns you want, if you want only data from `b` then you can do `a.key, b.*`

Comment: @rs. Ah, that takes care of it.  It seems like Hiro2k's answer contradicts your first sentence; however, your solution seems like the best one for my purposes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
select * from a INNER JOIN b USING (key)
```

The USING statement causes the key to only show up once in your result.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve the problem as I asked it.  I have the additional problem where my keys don't match up: I have to take the substring of one of the keys.  Is there syntax to allow substring(key1) = key2?

Comment: That's a sign of bad design. The keys in your tables should match up 100%. If you wanted to do that you could but not with the USING clause. You would have to change to using the ON clause, but then the duplicates show up again.

Comment: @Hiro2k That's a matter of VERY strong contention in DB circles. Personally, I think `USING` as a join condition is a horrible misfeature that leads to fragile SQL. The real fix is not to use `SELECT *` in production code - list the columns explicitly, always, without fail. That protects you against columns being added/reordered and helps the parser in most DBs give way more useful error messages too.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I'm talking about `NATURAL JOIN` as a "horrible misfeature," not `USING`. Too late at night here, my bad. `a INNER JOIN b USING(x)` is fine, just a more concise way of writing `a INNER JOIN b ON (a.x = b.x)` that collapses the equal columns into one in the result.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe NATURAL JOIN is solution for you:

```
SELECT * FROM a NATURAL JOIN b;
```

But if there are more duplicated key names and you want both of such keys in results, then natural join is not good for you.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new.  According to wikipedia: "Most experts agree that NATURAL JOINs are dangerous and therefore strongly discourage their use."  Probably going to go with the "Using" statement.

Comment: At the beginning I misunderstood the question. I thought that you wanted to remove all duplicated key names. And I agree, natural join is dangerous and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically name your fields instead of *, you will not have the duplicate keys, and the query will be faster (so i've heard).

```
select key, field1, field2, field3 from a, b where a.key = b.key
```

Comment: It shouldn't make the query faster on any sane DB I'm aware of, not unless you actually only want a small subset of the columns. Even then, it'll only help if the omitted columns are really big (ie: reduce cost of transferring the data to the client) or are stored out-of-line from the main tuple using a mechanism like PostgreSQL's `TOAST`, so the fetch of the big column(s) can be skipped entirely.

Comment: @canisrufus "Several hundred columns" might be part of your problem right there ;-) but I understand that clean and pretty designs don't always meet well with real-world performance demands. Depending on the situation you might want to consider a key/value extension type like PostgreSQL's `hstore`, or even *shudder* EAV design. Using `SELECT *` you tend to hate yourself the first time you have to add a column or - worse - insert one somewhere in the middle.

Comment: In my experience with postgresql, if there's a redundant column name in both tables and you try to limit it using "SELECT column_name" you'll just get an error saying "Ambiguous column name"